# Unable to mix the Matrices, in order to form list for plotting

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of points, in the form of `{x,y,z}`. My job is to plot them. But the problem I am facing is I am having a hard time to club the points in the format of `{x,y,z}`. I will explain, what I am trying to say.
This is just a minimal example of what I want to do.

```
X = 2;
Y = 4;
M1 = {{y^2,x},{-x,y}};
M2 = {{y,x},{x^2,-y^2}};
evM = Re@Table[Table[Eigenvalues[UnitStep[Y/2-y]M2+UnitStep[y-Y/2]M1],{x,1,X,0.5}],{y,1,Y,1}]
```

I want to plot the Eigenvalues `evM` with respect to `x` and `y`. How did I go about that I created the lists for `x` and `y`. Then I was trying `Flatten` to make data points out of them up, like `{xi,yi,evM(xi,yi)}`. But I failed terribly. Couldn't seem to make a list out of the `{xi}`,`{yi}` and `{evM(xi,yi)}`. In the format of `{xi,yi,evM(xi,yi)}`.
This is how I created the lists `{xi}` and `{yi}`.

```
xList = Range[1,2,0.5];
yList = Range[1,4,1];
xFList = ConstantArray[xList, Length@Transpose@evM];
yFList = ConstantArray[yList, Length@Transpose@evM];
```

Then, I am lost after this.
In general, my range of `x` and `y` is arbitrary. And My matrix `M` dimension can also be arbitrary, functional dependence on `x` and `y` can also be arbitrary. But constant for a single program.

*Here the idea of `y` is like time. At one time upto half of `Y` i.e.`Y/2` I have matrix `M1` and after that I have matrix `M2` for other half period till `Y`*.

Comment: `mat[x_, y_] := {{y^2, x}, {-x, y}}; triplesToPlot = 
 Flatten[Table[{x, y, Re@#} & /@ Eigenvalues[mat[x, y]], {x, 1, 2, 
    0.5}, {y, 1, 4, 1}], 2];` Will give a list of `{x,y,Real Part}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
X = 2;
Y = 4;
M1 = {{y^2, x}, {-x, y}};
M2 = {{y, x}, {x^2, -y^2}};
evM = Flatten[
   Table[Thread[{x, y, 
      Re@Eigenvalues[
        UnitStep[Y/2 - y] M2 + UnitStep[y - Y/2] M1]}], {x, 1, X, 
     0.5}, {y, 1, Y, 1}], 1];

ListPointPlot3D[evM, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[6]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can combine multiple indices in a single `Table` and generate your points at the same time, e.g.

```
Flatten[Table[{x, y, Eigenvalues[...]}, {x, 1, 2,0.5}, {y, 1, 4, 1}], 1]
```

However, `Eigenvalues` gives a list of all the, possibly complex valued, eigenvalues so you'll need to do some extra work to get points you can plot.

If you want the absolute value of the largest eigenvalue use:

```
Flatten[Table[
  Join[{x, y}, Abs[Eigenvalues[{{y^2, x}, {-x, y}}, 1]]], {x, 1, 2, 0.5},
    {y, 1, 4, 1}], 1]
```